# Java save Resources Folder to disk folder

Tags: java, file, copy, outputstream

I do have a Folder in my Ressources i want to extract to disk when the App is started the first time. I do have this peace of code here where I tried to copy them to disk, but all I get are empty files. The folder contains .gnh files. Where am I loosing my Bytes of the File?

```
public void getTemplates() throws URISyntaxException {
    final URL url = TemplateUtils.class.getResource("/templates/");
    if (url != null) {
        final File dir = new File(url.toURI());
        for (final File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            try {


                final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        PathManager.INSTANCE.getRootPath() + file.getName());

                final long writtenBytes = Files.copy(file.toPath(), outStream);
                LOG.info(writtenBytes);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();


            } catch (final IOException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the LOG.info(writtenBytes) says 0

EDIT:
When I copy simple text Files everything is working fine. But with those .gnh Files nothing is working anymore. Is there another way to extract those Files to disk?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with fileInfo? I logged the file.length() at this point and it was zero. So I tried a simple text file and my method worked. Looks like the problem is this stupid .gnh FileFormat. is there another way to copy/ extract a folder?

Comment: wrong comment . i misunderstood . deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: You need to create the File for the OutputStream first and then you can flush it.

```
    final File path = new File(
            PathManager.INSTANCE.getRootPath() + "templates");
    path.mkdirs();
        final File newFile = new File(path.toString()
                + File.separator + file.getName());
    newFile.createNewFile();
    final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
```